# Is there any function in jquery to remain same tab after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi everyone  i have a basic jquery tabs . I want to remain on same tab even after reloading the page . I tried local storage method but it doesn't work. Please give some suggestions to get out of it`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

// Show/Hide Tabs

  jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).siblings().slideUp(400);
  jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).delay(400).slideDown(400);
  // Change/remove current tab to active
  jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

  e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, you can do one thing:

1. When you navigate to the tab, use a `#hashbang` on it. i.e., Don't `return false;` or `event.preventDefault();`.
2. Based on the `window.location.hash`, get the current tab and activate it on `DOMReady`.

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $(".tab:not(#tab1)").hide();
  $(".tabs li a").click(function () {
    $(".tab:visible").hide();
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $($(this).attr("href")).show();
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
  if (window.location.hash.length > 0)
  {
    $(".tab:visible").hide();
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(window.location.hash).show();
    $('a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
.tabs li {display: inline-block;}
.tabs li a {text-decoration: none; display: block;}
.tabs li a.active {font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href="#tab1" class="active">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabcontent">
  <div class="tab" id="tab1">Tab 1 Contents</div>
  <div class="tab" id="tab2">Tab 2 Contents</div>
  <div class="tab" id="tab3">Tab 3 Contents</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you elaborate this praveen

Comment: @HariShankar Machaa, on the way fiddle da.

Comment: @HariShankar Have a look now!

Comment: thanks praveen i will check and tell you thanks a lot